# Fuji Xerox Docuprint CM305df Not detected in sane for scanning

Tags: debian

Is anyone able to help a techno tragic install a Fuji Xerox Docuprint CM305df please in Linux Mint 17 (Quiana) Cinnamon. I have tried to work out the thing with “sane” but cannot get any thing to detect the scanner (gscan2pdf, simplescan, xsane & Gimp)  printer works fine as a network printer No problem. I have used all the tips & tweaks I can find, even though it was a little nervy using the terminal in case I stuff things up. I have run “lsusb” it shows “Fuji Xerox inc” on a usb port & if I switch usb ports lsub picks it up on whatever port I plug it into. Whether this is just picking it up as a usb printer I cant say. All the effort over the last couple of weeks points to this in sane, but I don't know how to install it. If someone could please take me through it step by step I would be very grateful. Thank You in advance Linux\ Ubuntu society
  DESCRIPTION
       The  sane-xerox_mfp library implements a SANE (Scanner Access Now Easy)
       backend  that  provides  access  to  the  following  USB  and   network
       multifunction-peripheral:

```
          Phaser 3200MFP
          Dell MFP Laser Printer 1815dn
          Xerox Phaser 6110MFP
          Samsung CLX-3170fn & CLX-3175FW
          Samsung SCX-4200
          Samsung SCX-4300
          Samsung SCX-4500
          Samsung SCX-4500W
          Samsung SCX4725-FN
          Xerox WorkCentre 3119 Series
```

Comment: Return Message "No scanners were identified" . I,m new to forums as a previous Windows user you never have to do anything like this. All the files & stuff are there you just plug it in + the disc & it just works. Thanx for the tip I'll try the Linux forum for help, sorry I didn't understand what this forum IS for.

Answer (score 0):

See if your device shows up after running `scanimage -L`.  And see if it shows up.  If so, you can try `scanimage >image.pnm`.

You should probably ask this in the [Linux Mint Forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/).  Stack Exchange isn't designed for threads of follow-up questions.